# Mapping of 3 Objects

Tags: trigger, map

I have 3 Objects namely Billing Account, Subscription and Subscription charges&Products. I have the following lookup relationships:

1. Billing Account <= Subscription
2. Subscription <= Subscription charges&Products.

There is no direct relation between Billing Account and Subscription charges&Products.

Now, I need to populate 2 fields from Subscription charges&Products into Billing Account.

Can someone suggest how we can go forward with this requirement using Maps

Comment: I've tried to make the relationships that you have a bit more clear. Please edit them if I've gotten the direction of the relationship wrong. From the original wording, I assumed that `Subscription` has a lookup field to your Billing `Account`, and that `Subscription_Charges_Products__c` has a lookup to `Subscription`.

Comment: Also, have you made an attempt to write this code yourself? If you have, it would be helpful to [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: Try this using relation Subscription__r.Billing_Account__r.Value__c = Subscription_charge_Products_Custom_Field__C . I am assuming the field name in Subscription charges&Products is Subscription__C  and Billing_Account__c as look up field name.